# Multi line print

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

this is my code - it prints all in one line but i want it to be multiline. plz help

```
function display() 
{

        var divElements = document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = "The Ninja Centre Order Receipt" +
        document.getElementById("first").value +
        document.getElementById("last").value +
        document.getElementById("address").value +
        document.getElementById("suburb").value +
        document.getElementById("state").value +
        document.getElementById("postcode").value +
        document.getElementById("country").value +
        document.getElementById("email").value +
        document.getElementById("contact").value +
        document.getElementById("selection").value +  
        document.getElementById("result").value 

        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for `<br/>` tag like this:-

```
function display() 
{

        var divElements = document.getElementById("selection").innerHTML;
        var oldPage = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = "The Ninja Centre Order Receipt" + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("first").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("last").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("address").value + '<br/>' +
        document.getElementById("suburb").value  + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("state").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("postcode").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("country").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("email").value + <br/> +
        document.getElementById("contact").value + '<br/>'+
        document.getElementById("selection").value + '<br/>'+  
        document.getElementById("result").value 

        window.print();
        document.body.innerHTML = oldPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want theses values to be split onto different lines you need to either

- wrap each element in a `<p>` tag 
  or
- break the string up with a `<br>` tag after each value
  or
- some combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Add `'<br/>'` on the end of each line. You are writing in html (via js), in which 
 is the newline.